# Multiplying UInt64 by a Float

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have the following code in a playground:

```
import Foundation

var test : UInt64 = NSEC_PER_SEC // NSEC_PER_SEC is a CUnsignedLongLong
var test2 = 2 * test // this works
var test3 = 1.5 * test // this doesn't work
```

I'm trying to get a `Int64` value that is the number of nanoseconds in some `Float` representation of seconds for use with `dispatch_after`.

I've tried several variations of type casting, but I can't seem to come up with a way to get this result.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

### Solution

The solution in the answer below (thanks to @shucao) is to do the following:

```
var test3 = 1.5 * Double(test)
```

Interestingly, Swift takes `1.5` to be a `Double` as well. So, for instance, this does **not** work:

```
var flt : Float = 1.5
var test3 = flt * Double(test) // doesn't work
var test3 = Double(flt) * Double(test) // does work
```

So, in order to find the number of nanoseconds in an arbitrary number of seconds, both values have to be cast to `Double`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast `test` to `Double`

```
var test3 = 1.5 * Double(test)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I updated my post with an explanation. I wish there were a better way to do this, though.